# Groovy to list proper Url of Repository from Pipeline script from SCM (Git)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have Pipeline jobs that are defined as Pipeline script from SCM where Git is selected.
Example:
[Pipeline script from SCM image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TAOL.png)

I am trying to run a Groovy Script in the Script Console to report all jobs and the Repository URL configured in the GUI, but none of the solutions I have found such as getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl() are returning the correct Repository URL.

I don't know where it is getting the value from but getUrl() is just returning some other value that just does NOT match the value shown on GUI section of the Pipeline Definition.

Does anyone have any clue what code may work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Groovy script to get the Git URLs.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { jobitem ->
      if(jobitem instanceof org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob) {
        if(jobitem.definition instanceof org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition) {
          jobitem.definition.getScm().getRepositories().each { repo ->
                println("Job Name: " + jobitem.getName() + " URLs: " + repo.getURIs())

            } 
        }       
    }     
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I really could not find this solution anywhere. I had to look at the config.xml for the job and study the model to come up with this code to return the proper repository URL, Filepath and the Branch:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob;

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each {
  project = it.getFullName()
  if (it instanceof WorkflowJob) {
      myDef = it.getDefinition()
      try {
            myDef1 = myDef.getScm()
            myDef1.each {
                  println(project+"\t"+it.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()+"\t"+myDef.getScriptPath()+"\t"+it.branches[0]);
            }
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
            //println (project+"\t[Script]")
     }
  }

};
```